# Подменить вызовы функций во View flask приложения

Tags: python, flask, testng

Пробую протестировать вызовы endpoint`а flask приложения.
Во view содержится вызовы к сторонним апи.
Модуль(Blueprint) находиться в папке

> app/password

относительно корня приложения.
файл с view находится на ожном уровне с utils.

```
from .utils import call_ext_api
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask import Response

app_blue_print = Blueprint('password', __name__)

@app_blue_print.route('/pass', methods=['POST'])
def send_password():
    data = request.get_json()

    res = call_ext_api(data)

    if not res:
      return Response(status=404)
   return Response()
```

Для тестирования пробую исполльзовать pytest

```
from apps.password import utils

@pytest.fixture
def client(request, monkeypatch):

    def monkey_call_ext_api(data):
        """
            Патч-заглушка.
        """
        print('In patch')

    monkeypatch.setattr(utils, 'call_ext_api', monkey_call_ext_api)

    app = create_app(TestConfig)

    test_client = app.test_client()
    return test_client

def test_call_otp_pass(client):
    client.post(spec_end_point,
                content_type='application/json',
                data=json.dumps({
                     "field": "data"
                })
    )
```

Не удается подменить функцию call_ext_api.
Привел только один из попробованных вариантов.
Пробовал и патчить по празному:
 И в функции теста и в модуле и использовать декоратор @patch из стандартной библиотеки.
Подскажите как можно пропатчить функции внутри приложения flask?

Comment: Ваш `from .utils import call_ext_api` вытаскивает функцию из модуля utils и забирает себе, следовательно никакие изменения utils на функцию внутри views уже не смогут повлиять. Или меняйте функцию в views, или используйте функцию как `from . import utils` и `res = utils.call_ext_api(data)`

Comment: Спасибо. этот вариант тоже подходит.  Я "обернул" функцию `call_ext_api` в класс и иппортирую класс а потом в нем подменяю функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким методом.
"Обернул" функцию call_ext_api в класс.

```
class SomeClass:
   @staticmethod
   def call_ext_api():
      pass
```

Потом импортирую класс в коде и в тестах.
В тестах делаю подмену

```
from .utils import SomeClass

monkey_call_ext_api = MagicMock(return_value=200)
monkeypatch.setattr('apps.password.utils.SomeClass.call_ext_api', monkey_call_ext_api)
```

вариант предложенный @andreymal :

> импортировать модуль

тоже подходит, но в моем случае я хотел как можно меньше менять исходный код.
Возможно со временем я так сделаю.